# How to use parameters and execute correctly a useLazyQuery from Apollo client in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm learning Apollo client with VueJs (Composition API syntax), I got a query that searches a user by the name field, and What I'm trying to do is to **trigger the fetch with a @click event** on a button next to an input in which you should write the user's name.
So basically I'm trying to use **useLazyQuery** and pass the name prop as param in the query but I don't know how to do it.

```html
<div class="selectedUser">
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="Brian..."
        v-model="userSearched"
         />
         <p>{{userSearched}}</p>

         <button
           @click="load()">
         Search for a user
         </button>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed, reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';
import { useLazyQuery, useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HomeView',
  setup(){
const GET_USER_BY_NAME = gql`
      query getUser($name: String!){
        user(name: $name) {
          id
          name
          age
          username
          nationality
      }
    },
    `
const state = reactive({
      userSearched : ''
    });

     const {
        result: userSearhedResult,
        load      
        } = useLazyQuery(GET_USER_BY_NAME);
 
    
    ` return {
        users,
        error,
        loading,
        load, 
        ...toRefs(state)
       }
  }});
</script>
```

As you can see, my idea is/was to use the userSearched from the reactive() as param, but I'm not doing it right. Hope you share with me the correct way to do it. Thanks